# why docker container id not coming up when it is running?

Tags: docker

I have a docker file with entrypoint script as below

```
FROM centos:latest
MAINTAINER “HV"

#Add Environment variables here
ENV container docker

#Add Prerquisites
RUN yum install wget -y
RUN yum install unzip -y
RUN yum install make -y
RUN yum install sudo -y
RUN yum install libtool-ltdl -y
RUN yum install python3 python3-pip -y

#Install Git
RUN mkdir -p /home/Test/
RUN yum install git -y

#Copy Entrypoint script
COPY ilab_entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/

ENTRYPOINT ["ilab_entrypoint.sh"]

CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]
```

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

git clone git_url

exec "$@"
```

So i could build and run the container i don;t see the id when i am inside the container,

example,

when i run the docker container i can enter it but it remains as same localhost but no id

```
root@centos8-test:[/home/Test]: docker exec -it 3c2b5973f5c0 bash
```

`[root@centos8-test /]#`

it should be running as below instead

`[root@3c2b5973f5c0 /]#`

Comment: Maybe the container has the same hostname as your machine (host).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not related to the script, if you want to change the hostname you can specify it in the run command:

```
$ docker run --rm  -it python:3.9 bash           
root@2d97c319abcf:/# exit
exit
$ docker run --rm -it --hostname some-host python:3.9 bash                                   
root@some-host:/# exit
exit
```

Comment: Thanks much @ItayB this works for me, but by default the container id was coming up but why it is not there now soo asked...

Comment: If u share your dockerfile we can try to help

Comment: I have shared dockerfile now @ItayB

Comment: Tried to reproduce with no lack. BTW, the image id != container id so your expectation is wrong. Every new container you bring up will generate a new id